# Return response from VUEX actions to component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

So I have a component which has this method:

```
const message = {
  title: this.title,
  message: this.message,
  receiver: this.username
}
this.$store.dispatch('contactAuthor', message);
```

then this happens in actions.js:

```
const contactAuthor = ({commit}, payload) => {
    API.post('send-message', payload).then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 200 && response.data.success) {
          // WHAT TO RETURN HERE TO SET SUCCESS TO TRUE IN COMPONENT?
        } else {
          console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Something went wrong');
      });     
}
```

Now my component has data called `success: false` and I want to set it to `true` when I call the function from `actions.js` `contactAuthor`. How can I return `true` and set it to data `success` in component ?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I feel sending the data back to the component is not the ideal way. Instead, you can have another constant (like below) in actions.js and have a getter for the same. Access the getter in your component as a computed property.

```
// actions.js
const state = {
    api: {
        fetch: {
            inProgress: false,
            completed: false,
            success: false,
            error: false,
        },
        data: {}
    }
}

const getter = {
    'API_DATA': state => {
        return state.api
    }    
}

const mutations = {
    'SET_API_DATA_FETCH_IN_PROGRESS': state => {
        state.api.fetch.inProgress = true
        state.api.fetch.completed = false
        state.api.fetch.success = false
        state.api.fetch.error = false
        state.api.data = {}
    },
    'SET_API_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS': (state, payload) => {
        state.api.fetch.inProgress = false
        state.api.fetch.completed = true
        state.api.fetch.success = true
        state.api.fetch.error = false
        state.api.data = payload
    },
    'SET_API_DATA_FETCH_ERROR': (state, payload) => {
        state.api.fetch.inProgress = false
        state.api.fetch.completed = true
        state.api.fetch.success = false
        state.api.fetch.error = true
        state.api.data = payload
    }
}

const contactAuthor = ({ commit }, payload) => {
    commit('SET_API_DATA_FETCH_IN_PROGRESS')
    API.post('send-message', payload).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200 && response.data.success) {
            // WHAT TO RETURN HERE TO SET SUCCESS TO TRUE IN COMPONENT?
            commit('SET_API_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS', response)
        } else {
            commit('SET_API_DATA_FETCH_ERROR', response)
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        commit('SET_API_DATA_FETCH_ERROR', response)
        console.log('Something went wrong');
    });
}
```

```
// component.vue
computed: {
    apiDataFetchSuccess() {
      return this.$store.getters.API_DATA.fetch.success
    },
    apiData() {
      return this.$store.getters.API_DATA.data
    }
}
```

Comment: People need to upvote this answer. If you don't use the store to track the state, why do you use it in the first place?

Let me elaborate: 

No one is gonna stop you from passing a callback function to the payload of the action. If you do that, you can indeed, get a direct response from the action. But doing that defeat the whole concept of using a store in the first place, and any reactive framework in principle.

Comment: The place where this feels like it doesn't always make sense is in cases where the information you want to return from the action _doesn't belong_ in state. E.g. when making an API call, storing "call success" in state might be useless if you never need to look at it again after the call is done, and it may simply increase the complexity of the state and store (especially with multiple actions that call APIs). The alternative here would be to move the API call out of store entirely, but this also has the downside of forcing you to copy the call to each place you were calling the action before.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this worked.

```
const contactAuthor = (payload) => {
   return API.post('send-message', payload).then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 200 && response.data.success) {
          const trueMessage = true;
          return trueMessage;
        } else {
          console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Something went wrong');
      });     
}
```

returning promise from axios and then returning `trueMessage` from `contactAuthor` and then setting it up like this in component:

```
this.$store.dispatch('contactAuthor', message).then(data => {
  this.success = data;
});
```

Comment: what you received from callback ?  what's the value of `data` I am not seeing anything get resolved !

Comment: @SatyamPathak `data` is `true` because `data` is `trueMessage` from `API` call

Answer (score 0):

In your store mutations, you have to do something like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      API.post('send-message', payload).then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 200 && response.data.success) {
          const trueMessage = true;
          resolve(trueMessage)
        } else {
          reject('Something went wrong')
          console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        reject(error)
        console.log('Something went wrong');
      });
})
```

In your component do something like this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('contactAuthor', message)
.then( (success)  => {
   //OK, do something
})
.catch( (error) => {
   // ERROR, do something
});
```